# How do I pass this specific json objects/arrays in my dart code?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

```
{
"timestamp": [
    1610029800,
    1610030100,
    1610030400,
    1610030700,
    1610031000,
    1610031300,
    1610031600,
    1610031900,
    1610032200,
    1610032500,
    1610032800,
    1610033100,
    1610033400,
    1610033700,
    1610034000,
    1610034300,
    1610034600,
    1610034900,
    1610035200,
    1610035500,
    1610035800,
    1610036100,
    1610036400,
    1610036700,
    1610037000,
    1610037300,
    1610037600,
    1610037900,
    1610038200,
    1610038500,
    1610038800,
    1610039100,
    1610039400,
    1610039700,
    1610040000,
    1610040300,
    1610040600,
    1610040900,
    1610041200,
    1610041500,
    1610041800,
    1610042100,
    1610042400,
    1610042700,
    1610043000,
    1610043300,
    1610043600,
    1610043900,
    1610044200,
    1610044500,
    1610044800,
    1610045100,
    1610045400,
    1610045700,
    1610046000,
    1610046300,
    1610046600,
    1610046900,
    1610047200,
    1610047500,
    1610047800,
    1610048100,
    1610048400,
    1610048700,
    1610049000,
    1610049300,
    1610049600,
    1610049900,
    1610050200,
    1610050288,
    1610050800,
    1610051100,
    1610051400,
    1610051700,
    1610052000,
    1610052300,
    1610052600,
    1610052900,
    1610053200
],
"equity": [
    99993.3,
    100003.95,
    100020.49,
    100024.87,
    100023.04,
    100026.06,
    100033.77,
    100037.59,
    100038.22,
    100035.59,
    100032.06,
    100030.61,
    100027.34,
    100027.76,
    100027.04,
    100028.99,
    100032.05,
    100032.05,
    100031.77,
    100028.4,
    100024.87,
    100021.88,
    100025.1,
    100027.37,
    100026.72,
    100030.66,
    100035.4,
    100034.09,
    100033.68,
    100031.19,
    100030.15,
    100030.24,
    100030.56,
    100030.37,
    100030.85,
    100030.58,
    100030.34,
    100032.01,
    100032.23,
    100032.8,
    100035,
    100036.34,
    100036.38,
    100035.61,
    100033.77,
    100035.65,
    100037.89,
    100038.23,
    100037.36,
    100040.68,
    100041.19,
    100040.57,
    100037.46,
    100036.27,
    100035.21,
    100034.26,
    100035.17,
    100035.17,
    100033.73,
    100032.49,
    100030.69,
    100031.75,
    100030.87,
    100029.96,
    100028.21,
    100028.36,
    100029.78,
    100030.72,
    100030.57,
    100030.97,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null
],
"profit_loss": [
    5.64,
    16.29,
    32.83,
    37.21,
    35.38,
    38.4,
    46.11,
    49.93,
    50.56,
    47.93,
    44.4,
    42.95,
    39.68,
    40.1,
    39.38,
    41.33,
    44.39,
    44.39,
    44.11,
    40.74,
    37.21,
    34.22,
    37.44,
    39.71,
    39.06,
    43,
    47.74,
    46.43,
    46.02,
    43.53,
    42.49,
    42.58,
    42.9,
    42.71,
    43.19,
    42.92,
    42.68,
    44.35,
    44.57,
    45.14,
    47.34,
    48.68,
    48.72,
    47.95,
    46.11,
    47.99,
    50.23,
    50.57,
    49.7,
    53.02,
    53.53,
    52.91,
    49.8,
    48.61,
    47.55,
    46.6,
    47.51,
    47.51,
    46.07,
    44.83,
    43.03,
    44.09,
    43.21,
    42.3,
    40.55,
    40.7,
    42.12,
    43.06,
    42.91,
    43.31,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null
],
"profit_loss_pct": [
    0.00005640696061894037,
    0.00016292010434087564,
    0.0003283405172198249,
    0.00037214592280687437,
    0.00035384366430817564,
    0.00038404739144810466,
    0.00046115690676229443,
    0.000499361621224059,
    0.0005056623987400045,
    0.0004793591529194702,
    0.000444054796361871,
    0.0004295530068410442,
    0.0003968489711630415,
    0.0004010494895070052,
    0.00039384860091735323,
    0.0004133510075143272,
    0.0004439547840203481,
    0.0004439547840203481,
    0.00044115443845770566,
    0.00040745027936447357,
    0.00037214592280687437,
    0.0003422422326915141,
    0.00037444620666190207,
    0.00039714900818761033,
    0.000390648205988619,
    0.0004300530685486589,
    0.0004774589184305343,
    0.00046435730169102864,
    0.00046025679568858797,
    0.00043535372264937494,
    0.00042495243913098877,
    0.00042585255020469523,
    0.00042905294513342944,
    0.00042715271064449353,
    0.0004319533030375948,
    0.00042925296981647537,
    0.0004268526736199247,
    0.00044355473465425635,
    0.00044575500616776106,
    0.0004514557096345689,
    0.00047345842476961657,
    0.00048686007853369104,
    0.0004872601278997828,
    0.00047955917760251614,
    0.00046115690676229443,
    0.00047995922696860793,
    0.0005023619914697473,
    0.0005057624110815274,
    0.0004970613373690314,
    0.0005302654347546488,
    0.0005353660641723188,
    0.0005291652989978963,
    0.0004980614607842607,
    0.00048615999214303044,
    0.00047555868394159835,
    0.00046605751149691874,
    0.00047515863457550656,
    0.00047515863457550656,
    0.0004607568573962027,
    0.0004483553270473576,
    0.00043035310557322775,
    0.0004409544137746598,
    0.0004321533277206407,
    0.0004230522046420528,
    0.0004055500448755376,
    0.00040705022999838183,
    0.00042125198249463977,
    0.00043065314259779655,
    0.0004291529574749524,
    0.0004331534511358702,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null
],
"base_value": 99987.66,
"timeframe": "5Min"
}
```

and this is my Portfolio class in dart code:

```html
class PortfolioHistory {
  final List<int> dateTimeStamp;
  final List<double> equityValList;
  final String timeframe;
  PortfolioHistory( {this.dateTimeStamp, this.equityValList, this.timeframe});

  factory PortfolioHistory.fromJson(final json) {
    return PortfolioHistory(
       dateTimeStamp : json['timestamp'], 
        equityValList: json['equity'],
      timeframe: json['timeframe']
    );
  }

}
```

I am calling the JSON code above from an api, but there is the error:

> The following _TypeError was thrown building
> FutureBuilder(dirty, state:
> _FutureBuilderState#c9f1f): type 'FormatException' is not a subtype of type 'String'

I think that the error should be within the json code but I am not sure. Please help me anyone

Comment: Go to [JSON to Dart Converter](https://jsontodart.com)

Comment: Hello, the error is still here, the 'snapshot' variable from FutureBuilder has an error as snapshot.hasError is equal to true.

Comment: Going to need to post the code for you FutureBuilder and api request.  There seems to be a FormatException trying to be inserted into a string.